# While loops not working and crashing the console

Tags: c, while-loop, crash, crash-reports

Whenever I start this code in CodeBlocks, it crashes the console and returns:

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
int next, prev, max;

while (1) {
    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", next);
    if (next > prev) {
        prev = next;
        max = next;
    }
    if(next = 0){
        break;
    }
}
printf("Max number is: %d", max);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `prev` is not initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%d", next);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &next); // note & operator
```

The `%d` specifier expects the corresponding argument to be an expression of type `int *` - that is, a pointer to an `int`.   You're passing the (uninitialized, indeterminate) *value* stored in `next`, which is almost certainly not a valid pointer value.

Comment: Well color me purple, I completely missed that one...